# case insensitive splitting swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to split values in swift, and it works, but it is cAsE sEnSiTiVe. Is there a way of splitting them in swift 4 ignoring case?

```
"Hello There!"
"hello there!"
```

I am currently using `String.components(seperatedBy: "Th")` but that does only split the second string, `"hello there!"`. Is there a way to split them both?

Comment: You said below "Well, what I tried to do is create a search engine." This is a classic X/Y problem. You ask how to implement a small part of a specific solution to a problem rather than asking how to solve the problem. Case-insensitive splitting is kind of tricky, and splitting a long string in order to search is probably not a very good way to go about it. You should reframe your question in terms of the actual problem you are trying to solve rather than how to implement the solution you've chosen.

Comment: General Kenobi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
import Foundation

let str1 = "Hello There!"
let str2 = "hello there!"

extension String {
    func caseInsensitiveSplit(separator: String) -> [String] {
        //Thanks for Carpsen90. Please see comments below.
        if separator.isEmpty {
            return [self] //generates the same output as `.components(separatedBy: "")`
        }
        let pattern = NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: separator)
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
        let matches = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<self.utf16.count))
        let ranges = (0..<matches.count+1).map { (i: Int)->NSRange in
            let start = i == 0 ? 0 : matches[i-1].range.location + matches[i-1].range.length
            let end = i == matches.count ? self.utf16.count: matches[i].range.location
            return NSRange(location: start, length: end-start)
        }
        return ranges.map {String(self[Range($0, in: self)!])}
    }
}

print( str1.caseInsensitiveSplit(separator: "th") ) //->["Hello ", "ere!"]
print( str2.caseInsensitiveSplit(separator: "th") ) //->["hello ", "ere!"]
```

But I wonder what you want to do with `"hello "` and `"ere!"`.
(You lose case-info of the separator, if it matched with `"th"`, `"tH"`, `"Th"` or `"TH"`.)

If you can explain what you really want to do, someone would show you a better solution for it.

Comment: Well, what I tried to do is create a search engine. so e.g. a user types "he" it should return "herman", "henk", "hey", "he". I would then bolden the part out that the user typed: **he**rman, **he**nk, **he**y, **he**

Comment: @FrankHeijden, you should better note it in your question. _case insensitive splitting_ seems to be far from the best solution for your purpose.

Comment: @OOPer better check the `separator` character count before `try!` like so: `guard separator.count > 0 else { return [self] }` or throw an error.

Comment: @OOPer and maybe filter out empty components : `return ranges.map {String(self[Range($0, in: self)!])}.filter{$0.count > 0}`

Comment: @Carpsen90, thanks. But the latter case, my code seems to generate exactly what I expect. I want to generate the same output as `components(separatedBy:)` which does not filter out empty components. If you find some cases where my code does not generated the same result, please tell me. Anyway I'll update my answer to include your first suggestion, thank you again.

Comment: @OOPer why not simply `0...matches.count` instead of `0..<matches.count+1`

Comment: @LeoDabus, I want to express that the result Array has `matches.count+1` elements. And the latter, I know.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun another version using NSRegularExpression but extending StringProtocol:

**Swift 4 or later**

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func caseInsensitiveComponents<T>(separatedBy separator: T) -> [SubSequence] where T: StringProtocol, Index == String.Index {
        var index = startIndex
        return ((try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: String(separator)), options: .caseInsensitive))?.matches(in: String(self), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: utf16.count))
            .compactMap {
                guard let range = Range($0.range, in: String(self))
                else { return nil }
                defer { index = range.upperBound }
                return self[index..<range.lowerBound]
            } ?? []) + [self[index...]]
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing

```
let str1 = "Hello There!"
let str2 = "hello there!"

str1.caseInsensitiveComponents(separatedBy: "Th") // ["Hello ", "ere!"]
str2.caseInsensitiveComponents(separatedBy: "Th") // ["Hello ", "ere!"]
```

Answer (score 1):

An possible solution is to get the `range` of the separator with `.caseInsensitive` option and extract the substrings from its `lower-` and `upperBound`.

```
extension StringProtocol where Index == String.Index {

    func caseInsensitiveComponents(separatedBy separator: String) -> [SubSequence]
    {
        var result = [SubSequence]()
        var currentIndex = startIndex

        while let separatorRange = self[currentIndex...].range(of: separator, options: .caseInsensitive) {
            result.append(self[currentIndex..<separatorRange.lowerBound])
            currentIndex = separatorRange.upperBound
        }
        return result + [self[currentIndex...]]
    }
}
```

Comment: In Swift 4 or later it is better to extend StringProtocol and constrain Index to String.Index

Comment: @LeoDabus Brilliant 

Comment: I think we *close the file* now.

Comment: Note I have problems with this technique when `.regularExpression` option is set, and a non greedy pattern (eg `.*?`) is used . The parts are empty and currentIndex doesn’t advance. So loops forever.  This isn’t an issue using `NSRegularExpression` and `matches`.

Answer (score 0):

You could lower case the whole string first:

```
let s = "Hello There!".lowercased().components(separatedBy: "th")
```

Comment: I know, but I need them to be as they were and not lowercased

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood what you are trying to achieve, but you can try this.

```
var str = "Hello There!"
var str2 = "hello there!"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let split1 = str.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: "th", with: " ")
    let split2 = str2.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: "th", with: " ")

    print(split1) //hello  ere!
    print(split2) //hello  ere!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter for a list of items containing a certain keyword, split the strings is the wrong approach. All you need is a simple check whether that keyword appears in the item:

```
let queryStr = "th"
let items = [
    "Hello There!",
    "hello there!"
]

let filterdItems = items.filter {
    return $0.range(of: queryStr, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
}
```